# PHP Create file and download file

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a program, that lets you upload 2 files, run some code and then create a new file and download it, with the new data.

I've searched, and it seems like i'm doing the same, but it won't create a file, it just prints the text on the website.

This is the code.

```
    header("Content-type: text/plain");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=unique_ips.txt");
    echo 'IP addresses only found in file A:' . "\n";
    echo $array_a_result . "\n\n";
    echo 'IP addresses only found in file B:' . "\n";
    echo $array_b_result;
    exit();
```

It doesn't seem to care about the second header.

Comment: WHERE does this run? If it's not sent before other output, then it won't work - the header output has to be the first output that is sent.

Comment: Have you tried using "application/octet-stream" for your `Content-type`?

Answer (score 0):

Remember not to echo anything before `header()`. I just tested the code below. Should work as expected!

```
<?php
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myfile.txt');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
flush();
echo 'IP addresses only found in file A:' . "\n";
echo $array_a_result . "\n\n";
echo 'IP addresses only found in file B:' . "\n";
echo $array_b_result;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to imagine what you what is going on before the Code you posted, however, it would be advised that if you are doing a download, you should be careful not to output any text (even white-space) until after that part of the code has fully run. Having even a single white-space before `<?php` would raise an Error. Here is a function you may want to try out (if you will):

```
    <?php

        /**
         * FULL-NAME OF THE FILE TO DOWNLOAD
         * @param $downloadFileName
         * NEW-NAME FOR THE FILE... DO NOT USE EXTENSIONS LIKE .pdf OR .doc OR .txt
         * @param null $newFileName
         * @return bool
         *
         */
        function processDownload($downloadFileName, $newFileName=null) {
            $ext              = pathinfo($downloadFileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if(!$newFileName){
                $newFileName  = basename($downloadFileName);
            }else{
                $newFileName .= "." . $ext;
            }
            if(file_exists($downloadFileName)){
                $size       = @filesize($downloadFileName);
                header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $newFileName );
                header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
                header('Expires: 0');
                header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
                header('Pragma: public');
                header('Content-Length: ' . $size);
                readfile($downloadFileName);
                return TRUE;
            }
            return FALSE;
        }
```

If you opted to try out this Function, it is advised to make it the first function call at the top of your Script like this:

```
<?php  
        // NOTICE THAT THERE IS NO WHITE-SPACE BEFORE PHP.
        // AND NO OUTPUT WAS SENT (IE: NOTHING ECHOED OUT...)

        processDownload(__DIR__ . "/downloads/unique_ips.txt", "Unique-IPs");

        // FROM HERE ON, YOU MAY ECHO WHATEVER YOU WISH...
        // echo $whatever;
        // echo $youWish;
        // echo $may;
        // echo $nowBeEchoed;
        // echo $afterCalling;
        // echo $theFunctionAbove;

        echo 'IP addresses only found in file A:' . "\n";
        echo $array_a_result . "\n\n";
        echo 'IP addresses only found in file B:' . "\n";
        echo $array_b_result;


        function processDownload($downloadFileName, $newFileName=null) {
            $ext              = pathinfo($downloadFileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if(!$newFileName){
                $newFileName  = basename($downloadFileName);
            }else{
                $newFileName .= "." . $ext;
            }
            if(file_exists($downloadFileName)){
                $size       = @filesize($downloadFileName);
                header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $newFileName );
                header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
                header('Expires: 0');
                header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
                header('Pragma: public');
                header('Content-Length: ' . $size);
                readfile($downloadFileName);
                return TRUE;
            }
            return FALSE;
        }
```